# Ошибка в org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server, mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Ситуация такая. Стоит на моей машине mysql 5.1 сервер. В моём приложении есть вот такие проперти:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thanlyua
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=****
```

Запускаю локально, всё работает. Теперь размещаю на хостинге jelastic.com. Там сервер имеет тот же localhost:3306 адрес. Создаю такую же базу и пользователя, т.е все проперти остаются, только пароль другой. И вот ошибка:

> `ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter
> - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)`

Что я не так делаю? Целый день мучаюсь, не могу понять, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здравствуйте,
Мы представители Jelastic.
Постараемся помочь вам с вашей проблемой!

1)Строка подключения должна быть следующего вида:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql.magazin.jelastic.com/thanlyua
```

thanlyua - я так понимаю, это имя созданной вами БД. Если это так, то все правильно.

2) По поводу логина и пароля...

```
  jdbc.username=root
  jdbc.password=****
```

Эти значения вы получили на свой имейл, НО они служат для входа в админку базы данных по адресу:

```
mysql.magazin.jelastic.com
```

После входа в админку вам необходимо создать Нового юзера, которому вы укажите user_name и user_password, которые и укажите в своем коде:

```
  jdbc.username=user_name
  jdbc.password=user_password
```

На будущее, если есть какие-то вопросы по Jelastic, вы можете обращаться по адресу (тех поддержка):

```
   http://support.jelastic.com
```

Comment: спасибо! всё получилось)